# git checkout failing because branch already exists

Tags: git, github, version, controls

I am trying to checkout a branch that I was checking out with success in the past, and I can't check it out anymore. Here are the different messages I am getting. The easy solution would be to reset my folder, do a `git init` and `git clone`, but I do not want to reset my git folder as I set up things like git hooks (`post-checkout`, `post-merge`, etc). How could I get this to work again without resetting everything?

`fatal: A branch named 'stage' already exists.`

`git fatal: reference is not a tree`

`error: refs/heads/stage does not point to a valid object!`

`fatal: bad object stage`

Answer (score 7):

The way to solve this in a clean way is to delete your corrupted branch in `.git/refs/heads/your_branch_name`.

Answer (score 1):

In Git branch is simply a pointer. The pointer is to the `SHA-1` of the current commit in the branch and this information is stored in the file you just deleted: `.git/refs/heads/<your_branch_name>`

If you wish to verify that your repository does not contains any more loose objects (dangaling) or un-reached branches check it with this:

```
git fsck --full
```

Comment: I am getting a whole lot of `dangling blobs`, what should I do with them?

Comment: Basiclly nothing, you can recover "lost" data form those dangaling files if  you need it.

Comment: How to recover them?

Comment: You can run a `git cat-file -p <SHA-1>` and you will see the content.

Comment: great, and if I want to get rid of the dangaling data, where is that located, inside of `.git`?

Comment: You have to run a `git gc` but you don't want to do it unless you know EXACTLY!!! what it does. Leave it as it is

Comment: ______ ______

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you and if you learned something new. Thank you in advance.